# Laravel Config::get('application.aliases') returns null

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel, trying to ease the learning curve i saw this Code Completion Code snippet i wanted to try out from [here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=742&p=1)

```
Route::get('ccc', function() {

        $aliases = Config::get('application.aliases');

        $new_line = '<br>';

        echo '&lt;?php'.$new_line.$new_line;

        foreach ($aliases as $alias => $name_space)
        {
            echo 'class '.$alias.' extends '.$name_space.'{};'.$new_line;
        }
    });
```

However, `Config::get('application.aliases')` returns null in a fresh install (already checked `app/config/app.php` and everything seems fine), what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$aliases = Config::get('app.aliases');
```

Instead of :

```
$aliases = Config::get('application.aliases');
```

Here `app.aliases` will retrieve the `aliases` array from the `app/config/app.php` file and here `app` points to `app.php` file and `aliases` points to `aliases` array in this `app.php` file, because `Config::get('...')` will look for `files/arrays` inside the `app/config` directory, ss provide the right path (`subdirectoryname.filename.arraykeyname`).

Comment: Ah! Clearly this route snippet was written in Laravel 3, as in Laravel 4 the directory name changes, thanks for the reply, explanation & question fixes!